# React DND accessing the target object from the drop function

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I have a list of tiles that are draggable and a list of tiles that are dropable targets.

When I drag and drop a tile in the React DND drop function I can access the details of the tile being dragged, but I need to know WHERE it has been dropped.

I've gone over the documentation and the closest thing that I could find is `monitor.targetID` but that targetId is generated by ReactDND library and so it doesn't give me enough to find which component my dragged tile has been dropped on.

Here is what I have so far

```
import { useDrag, useDrop } from 'react-dnd'

function Tile({ letter, onClick, index, draggable , contextStyles , guessId}) {

  const dropLetter = (letter, monitor) => { 
    console.log(letter, 'dropLetter')
    return {dropResult: 'dropResult'}
  }

  const [{ isDragging }, dragRef] = useDrag({
    type: 'letter',
    item: {letter, index, draggable, guessId},
    collect: (monitor) => ({
        isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
    }),
    end: (item, monitor) => { console.log('endDrag', item, monitor.getDropResult())}
  })

  const [{ isOver, item }, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
    accept: "letter",
    item: { letter , index, draggable , guessId},
    drop: dropLetter,
    collect: (monitor) => ({
      isOver: !!monitor.isOver({shallow: false}),
      itemType: monitor.getItemType(),
      item: monitor.getItem(),
    })
  }));

  return (
    <li
      ref={(node) => dragRef(drop(node))}
      onClick={ onClick }
      className={ `${styles.Tile } ${contextStyles}`}
      draggable={ draggable }
      index={ index }>
        <div className={ styles.TileLetter}>
          { letter }
          {isDragging && ''}
          { isOver && 'isOver'}
        </div> 
    </li>
  )
}

export default Tile
```

[image]